# Get PHP object property, but do not be able to change original object property

Tags: php, oop

```
class Slider {
    private $slides;

    private $dublicate;

    public function get_slide($id) {

        foreach ( $this->slides as $slide ) {
            if ( $slide->id === $id ) {
                $this->dublicate = $slide;
                return $this->dublicate;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function add_slide($slide) {
        $this->slides[] = $slide;
    }

    public function get_slides() {
        return $this->slides;
    }
}

class Slide {
    public $id;

    public $name;
}

$slider = new Slider();

$slide = new Slide();
$slide->id = 5;
$slide->name = 'old_name';

$slider->add_slide($slide);

var_dump($slider->get_slides());

$editable = $slider->get_slide(5);
$editable->id = 6;
$editable->name = 'new_name';

var_dump($slider->get_slides());
```

First var_dump gives this result:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(Slide)#2 (2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(5)
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "old_name"
  }
}
```

and second var dump:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(Slide)#2 (2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(6)
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "new_name"
  }
}
```

So as you can see the value of original $slider->slides array has been changed. How can I get $slider->slides value that does not "connected" with it's original value ?

I need $slider->slides value but i don't want be able to "touch" the original object.

Comment: Ever heard of OOP, protected properties, getters and setters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand you correctly you are looking for [clone](http://php.net/clone):

```
$editable = clone $slider->get_slide(5);
$editable->id = 6;
$editable->name = 'new_name';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You have understand me correctly and your solution is working.

Comment: @Aram810 so, you should mark this as the accepted answer. That's the meaning of "accepted answer" ;)

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to use something which is called `getters` in OOP parlance. This is simply a method who's only task is to return a private/protected property.
The fact that the property is `private` or `protected` is required in order to restrict it from being manipulated outside of the object/class itself. All `public` methods are available to be changed by anyone at any time, as that is exactly what the `public` keyword means.

In summary, change your class to something like this:

```
class Slide {
    private $id;
    private $name;

    /**
      * @return string The name of the slide.
      */
    public get_name () {
        return $name;
    }

    /**
      * @param string $name The new display name of the slide.
      */
    public function set_name ($name) {
        // Normally one has some validation logic here, to ensure valid input.
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

Once you've done then you can `clone` the object, by using something like this:

```
$original = new Slides ();
$ediable = clone $original;
$editable->set_name ('New name');
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but the answers of R. Soons and Marina are more suitable for my case.

Comment: I've expanded upon my answer to include the cloning of objects. Sorry I missed it in the first run.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make the object properties protected, make getter functions for them and don't create setters. That way you can get the property but can't change it's value. Simple example:

```
class Something{
    protected $some;
    protected $thing;

    public function __construct($some, $thing){
        $this->some = $some;
        $this->thing = $thing;
    }

    public function getSome(){
       return $this->some;
    }
    public function getThing(){
       return $this->thing;
    }
}
```

You set the properties in the constructor when initialising the object, then you can't touch those properties, but can get them.

Answer (score 0):

You can  replace return this->dublicate;  with return clone $this->dublicate;